# Error while installing netcdf4-python

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

I am trying to install netcdf4-python by following https://code.google.com/archive/p/netcdf4-python/wikis/UbuntuInstall.wiki
I had installed HDF5 successfully but when i was installing netCDF4, in "**make**"command, am getting the below errors

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:682: recipe for target 'ncgen3' failed
make[2]: *** [ncgen3] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/farook/Downloads/netcdf-4.4.1/ncgen3'
Makefile:691: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/farook/Downloads/netcdf-4.4.1'
Makefile:538: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Could you add _gcc_ error lines that come before the _collect2_ line?

Comment: Well yeah, this is my whole error http://pastebin.com/72ncwVgy

Comment: Probably your library paths are not set up correctly. I would try googling for __"libnetcdf.so: undefined reference to"__. THere are many similar issues with some answers.

Comment: Is there a reason why you try to install `netCDF4-python`, `HDF5` and/or `netCDF` manually? I think that most package managers include `netCDF4-python`, if not you could try `pip`, if not I would try to install `netCDF4-python` against `netCDF` from the package manager, and compiling *everything* manually would really be my last resort.

Comment: Yeah i did a pip install. That works. Thank you.